# webContents.printtoPDF() always returns empty data of length 661 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron

My code looks like the following:

```
function pdfSettings(h, w) {
  var MICRONS_PER_IN = 25400;

  var option = {
      landscape: false,
      marginsType: 0,
      printBackground: true,
      printSelectionOnly: false,
      pageSize:{width:(w * MICRONS_PER_IN), height:(h * MICRONS_PER_IN)},
  };
  return option;
}
```

and

```
  win.webContents.printToPDF(pdfSettings('8.25','5.375'), function(err, data) {
    fs.writeFile('/Users/me/.myapp/test.pdf', data, function (error) {
      if (err) {
          return console.log(err.message);
      }
      else { 
        console.log("shouldn't be here"); 
        console.log(data.length);
      }
    });
  });
```

This produces a new pdf file with the correct dimensions, but is blank.

`win` is a new browserwindow object that has been opened, and I can see the content within it. I suspect that this is some issue with the browserwindow content not being available yet, but putting this inside of a ready event doesn't seem to do anything or even prevents it from firing at all.

The length of the data (and pdf filesize) is always 661 bytes regardless of the browserwindow content. Probably the minimum pdf template size or something.

My fallback strategy of using wkhtmltopdf instead is unviable (some css3 features are unavailable), so I have to make this work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand the psychology of how, 30 seconds after clicking "Post Your Question" I always figure it out myself and I'm tempted to delete this... but there doesn't seem to be another version of this on SO, so here goes.

The x.printToPDF() needs to be wrapped in an event handler for the webContents object, like so:

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
```

`did-finish-load` is the correct event for this issue. Also, there is no shame in copy-pasting the event names to avoid typos.